# Constant Update of Rails Partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, refresh, partial-views

In my index.html.erb there is this code where the partial is called:

```
<% @leagues.each do |league| %>
  <td class="last_updated">
    <%= render "last_updated", { league: league } %><br>
  </td>
<% end %>
```

and in my index.html.erb this code is also included

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $('.last_updated').load('refresh_last_updated');
    }, 5000);
});
```

in my controller I try to update the @last_updated cause this is the variable I need refreshed everytime this partial is reloaded and then I try to reload the partial keeping everything the same but this variable.

```
def refresh_last_updated
  @last_updated = BetResult.last_updated 
  render :partial => "last_updated"
end
```

Here is the partial

```
<%= @last_updated[league] %>
```

But the code is crashing it says

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `league' for #<#<Class:0x00000003d86b90>:0x000000075ad000>):
```

So the ajax call seems to be working.  The routes seem to be working.  The right control method seems to be called.  But then when it tries to reload the partial it doesn't have the parameters that it was given when loaded initially.  I'm not sure it has the @last_updated variable either available in the partial when refreshed... What am I doing wrong? How do I make this work?

Comment: The `leauge` variable isn't set anywhere in the `refresh_last_updated` action you included - what do you expect it to be?

Comment: do you need "<%= render partial: "last_updated", locals: {last_updated: @last_updated} %> "?